# Operate spearman correlation and p-value every 29 rows in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a matrix containing 152511 rows and 2 columns (*K* and *A*). I want to get the Spearman correlation and its p-value for every 29 rows, so I'll have 5259 correlations and p-values.

How do I operate it in Python?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you share with us what you have tried so far?

Comment: @medium-dimensional I tried using pandas groupby but it only brings up the correlation value. Now I calculate the correlation and p-value manually every 29 rows with scipy. Is there a way to loop every 29 rows?

Comment: Pleas see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/7789963) on how to iterate over rows of a DataFrame with pandas.